# FloatingActionButton cause CreateCircularReveal to fail

Tags: android

I have a fragment with an card view and when I try to add a FloatingActionButton thats cause the animation to fail.. The view just appear without an animation.. The Width and Height and radius is all correct but the animation dosen't run. This just occur the first time that the animation runs.. I use a regular Close button for this release..

CODE

```
public static void ToogleView(View myView, bool show, Func<int> param = null) {

    // get the center for the clipping circle
    int cx = myView.Width / 2;
    int cy = myView.Height / 2;

    // get the final radius for the clipping circle
    float finalRadius = (float) Math.Sqrt(cx * cx + cy * cy);

    // create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
    Animator anim;
    if (show) {
        anim = ViewAnimationUtils.CreateCircularReveal (myView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);
    } else {
        anim = ViewAnimationUtils.CreateCircularReveal (myView, cx, cy, finalRadius, 0);
    }
    anim.SetDuration (500);
    anim.AnimationEnd += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
        if(param != null) {
            param();
        }

        if(!show) {
            myView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
        }
    };
    // make the view visible and start the animation
    myView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    anim.Start();
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mapFragmentRoot"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:layout_height="0dp">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/mapFragmentMapCointatiner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ProgressBar
                        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:text="Hämtar närmaste hållplatser"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:paddingTop="60dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ProgressBar
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <!--android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/MapFragmentfabClose"
        android:elevation="12dp"
        card_view:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_white_48dp"
        card_view:layout_anchor="@id/header"
        card_view:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end" /-->

</FrameLayout>
```